# URL shortner Api

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer

I am using URL Shortener API to shorten our mobile app download link. (https://www.googleapis.com/)
We have some restrictions on our server such that we don't allow unrecognized IP access. 
So I would like to know what would be the IP range that googles use when the URL is shortened using this API (https://www.googleapis.com/).
This will help us to configure our security settings to allow access to these IP's

google-apis-explorer

Comment: GoogleAPIs uses same IP as of google. The exact IP range depends upon the country from which you are accessing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "using the URL Shortener API", are you referring to making calls to this API from your server (as in outbound traffic is IP restricted) or using the short URL to reach your server (as in inbound traffic is IP restricted)? I'll go ahead and answer both possibilities, but please clarify if these weren't what you meant.

#### If you're trying to allow calls to this API from your server with outbound traffic IP restricted

The URL shortener API can be called through any of Google's IP addresses. There's no way to get a list of these because they will vary by location, load balancing, etc. Plus, you wouldn't want to attempt to restrict by IP this way because whitelisting even one of Google's IP addresses would allow calls from your server to all of Google's services. This likely includes any service hosted on Google Cloud, which could be a proxy, meaning literally anything in the world could be called this way; you'd be entirely eliminating IP restrictions on your server.

#### If you're trying to shorten your server's URLs using this API and your server has inbound traffic IP restricted

You shouldn't need to do anything. These URLs are just domain redirects. In the end, the user ends up visiting your website (server) using its actual long URL (there's no proxying), so just whitelist the allows users' IPs and it should work.